# Free alternatives to nike training club for windows or linux pc

Tags: workout, tracking

Are there free alternatives for the [Nike Training Club](http://www.nike.com/us/en_us/c/womens-training/apps/nike-training-club), which run on a windows or linux pc or just online via web-browser?

List of features, from the [iTunes App Store description](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nike-training-club/id301521403?mt=8):

> - Full-body workouts for 30 or 45 minutes. Targeted and professional athlete workouts for 15 minutes. Set a favorite workout as your Quick-Start.
> - 130 multi-dimensional, multi-directional drills build on the fundamentals of strength, cardio, interval and core training.
> - Exclusive rewards including workouts from Rihanna’s personal trainer, professional athletes, celebrities, yoga instructors and more.
> - Simple functionality optimizes every workout. Select your goal and fitness level, then choose from a list of workouts that meet your criteria.
> - Set your workout to albums and playlists from your own music library.
> - Audio guidance keeps you on track and motivated while working out.
> - Access step-by-step instructions and video demonstrations for every drill at any time.
> - Track details of your workout history and training progress.
> - Share your workout and reward status on Facebook and Twitter.

Comment: Please be more precise about what it does or what you expect from an alternative to fulfill your needs.

Comment: @Informaficker I have just seen Nike Training Club and it seems to be a very interesting app. However I don't have an iphone/ipad, in addition I find it better to have something like this on pc. So I just want to ask if there is something which comes very close to this for other platforms as well.

Comment: Most of the fitness programs you're looking for tend to be mobile-based (in the sense that people don't exercise right next to a computer), but generally they should have an online counterpart available via regular web browser. You might want to look at [DailyBurn](http://www.dailyburn.com/) which claims to have custom fitness plans or [JEFIT](http://www.jefit.com/) which has some exercise routines as well. [Fivi](https://www.fivi.com/) also might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

With free alternatives, you aren't going to come across too many that can rival a Nike premium app. In reality, you would probably need to use a combination of one or more different apps to do so.

If you wanted randomly generated circuit training or workout routines, try: [sworkit.com](http://sworkit.com). It randomly generates workouts based off of your desired program level, and provides guides on doing each exercise.

If you already have a program in mind and wanted to track your progress/history, search for that specific program in the Play/App Store. When I did StrongLifts I found at least 5 suitable free apps to use for monitoring my progress.

If you are looking more for the social aspect of working out, try [fitocracy.com](http://fitocracy.com). It turns fitness into a game of "leveling up" where you can compete and play with your friends.