# What are some of the body weight workouts to do post run?

Tags: running, workout, health, bodyweight-exercises, exercise-ball

I am looking for some exercise to do at home without needing any weights. I only have access to a medicine ball.

I'm looking for exercises that complement and will help me with running. Like box jumps, step ups, etc.

Comment: Voting to close this because there's a nearly infinite list of exercises that can be suggested. If you can specifically say what you're trying to achieve (balanced total body, upper body, bigger wrists, whatever), folks might be able to get you in the right direction. Also, do you have access to rings, a suspension trainer (TRX), or pullup bar?

Comment: Thanks Eric! I only have access to medicine ball. I am looking for exercise that complement and help with getting better at running like box jumps/step ups etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the top intensive bodyweight exercises?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4578/what-are-the-top-intensive-bodyweight-exercises)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POdzasJklxw

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your goal as a runner; are you looking to compete? Or perhaps you are just looking to maintain good cardiovascular fitness, or lose weight?

What is necessary for all runners, regardless of your overall goal is to protect yourself against potential injury. [A study by Runner's World put the annual injury rate for runners at 66%](http://www.runnersworld.com/health/the-10-laws-of-injury-prevention). The most common injuries for runners are all caused to some degree by weak hips. You could do a [illiotibial band rehab routine](http://strengthrunning.com/2011/02/the-itb-rehab-routine-video-demonstration/) after your run to mitigate this.

You should also consider doing core strengthening exercises, as having a strong core is what allows the rest of your body to exert power effectively, and it will also protect you from injury. Straightforward bodyweight exercises good for strengthening your core include lunges, planks, pistol squats, push-ups, and side planks,

Comment: The ITB / hip strengthening idea is fairly solid. I would imagine most runners find themselves dealing with IT issues at one point or another.